# Optimal table with N:1 foreign key column

Tags: sql-server, index, foreign-key

I have an MS SQL table like this:

```
TABLE myLog(
  [LogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [ThingID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [Action] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_myLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [LogID] ASC
)
```

`ThingID` is a foreign key for a `myThings` table identity column.

`myLog` can contain many rows for any `ThingID`.

What are the best ways to index or key `myLog` given that a typical query will request all rows for a particular `ThingID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just put a non-clustered index on ThingID.  A and declare the relationship.

Comment: Syntax please? (For the win ;)

Comment: Why not just do it in SSMS?  I never write that syntax.

Comment: I can't find anything in SSMS 2016 that will let me create an index on a column that is not a primary key.

Comment: Go in design (right click table) and the right click any column nam